# Sazonov topology on a separable Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be real and separable Hilbert space. Introduce on $H$ a topology  $\tau_{\text{nuc}}(H,H)$ as the weakest topology oh $H$ with respect to which all the quadratic forms $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ are continuous, where $T:H\to H$ is positive, symmetric and nuclear.

How is continuity defined in this topology? for example, does for a function $f:H\to \mathbb{C}$ the statement $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists T_\epsilon $(that s symmetric positive and nuclear) such that $$|f(0)-f(x)|\leq \langle T_\epsilon x,x\rangle +\epsilon$$ 
mean $f$ is continuous with respect to the strong topology on $\mathbb{C}$ and this topology?
Is requiring $f$ to be continuous in this topology a stronger or weaker condition than continuity in the original (strong) topology?